# PHP web scraping

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I use php web scraping, and I want to get the price (3.65) on Sunday form the html code below:

```
     <tr class="odd">
       <td >
           <b>Sunday</b> Info
           <div class="test">test</div>
       </td>
       <td>
       &euro; 3.65 *

       </td>
    </tr>
```

But I don't find the best regex to do this...
I use this php code:

```
    <?php
        $data = file_get_contents('http://www.test.com/');

        preg_match('/<tr class="odd"><td ><b>Sunday</b> Info<div class="test">test<\/div><\/td><td>&euro; (.*) *<\/td><\/tr>/i', $data, $matches);
        $result = $matches[1];
    ?>
```

But no result... What's wrong in the regex? (I think it's because of the new lines/spaces?)

Comment: regex on "&euro; ([0-9.]*) " instead to get the price. If it's among others, you could split() it first. Watch out for special regex characters too, like the obvious * after the price!

Comment: But I also need to use the "Sunday", because there are also other days...

Comment: /Sunday(.*)&euro; ([0-9.]*)/s will give me the longest possible answer, is there a way to get the shortest answer? If that's possible, that could work...

Comment: If you don't have permission to scrape from the site, then don't do it. If you do have permission, then ask for a pricelist feed in XML, which will be designed for data extraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are the spaces between the tags.
there a line breaks, tabs and/or spaces.

your regex doesn't match to them.

you also need to setup your preg_match for multiline!

i think it is more easy to use xpath for scraping.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use regular expressions, HTML is not regular.

Instead, use a DOM Tree parser like `DOMDocument`. This [`documentation`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) may help you.

The `/s` switch should help you with your original regex though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace newlines with '' and then perform the regexp again.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
$uri = ('http://www.test.com/');
$get = file_get_contents($uri);

$pos1 = strpos($get, "<tr class=\"odd\"><td ><b>Sunday</b> Info<div class=\"test\">test</div></td><td>&euro;");
$pos2 = strpos($get, "*</td></tr>", $pos1);
$text = substr($get,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1);
$text1 = strip_tags($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP DOMDocument Object. We're going to parse the HTML DOM data from the web page

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($data);

    $trs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr'); // this gives us all the tr elements on the webpage

    // loop through all the tr tags
    foreach($trs as $tr) {
        // until we get one with the class 'odd' and has a b tag value of SUNDAY
        if ($tr->getAttribute('class') == 'odd' && $tr->getElementsByTagName('b')->item(0)->nodeValue == 'Sunday') {
            // now set the price to the node value of the second td tag
            $price = trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Instead of using DOMDocument for web scraping, it's a bit tedious, you can get your hands on SimpleHtmlDomParser, it's open source.